# jquery passing value of input to fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox and I want to display a value which is inputted on its parent page but it comes back undefined...any ideas how I can get this working?

```
$(this).parent().find('input[id="your_name"]').val();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to in your code? Also, if you are selecting by id, you can simply do `$("#your_name").val()` as id attributes should be unique.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, I think I got what you meant,

```
$('#various').click(function(){

var txt=$('#myNameInput').val();
$.fancybox({
        'titlePosition'        : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'        : 'none',
        'content' : txt,
        'transitionOut'        : 'none',
    });

return false;

});
```

check the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/QjcXA/1/

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for, how would I display the content bit in a div in my popup? Thanks

Comment: `var txt="<div>" + $('#myNameInput').val()+ "</div>";` [link]http://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/QjcXA/3/ I hope this is what you asked for. And you can mark this answer as correct , it will help other users!